# What is the fastest way to populate one pandas dataframe based on values from another pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe **position**

```
        row    column
  1      3     Brazil
  2      6     USA
  3      3     USA
  4      7     Canada
```

and another **x**

```
        Brazil   Canada  USA
  1     False    False   False
  2     False    False   False
  3     False    False   False
  4     False    False   False
  5     False    False   False
  6     False    False   False
  7     False    False   False
```

I want to populate the second one based on the values from the first one, so the result is:

```
        Brazil   Canada  USA
  1     False    False   False
  2     False    False   False
  3     True     False   True
  4     False    False   False
  5     False    False   False
  6     False    False   True
  7     False    True    False
```

I'm doing that using **iterrows()**

```
  for i, r in positions.iterrows():
      x.at[r['row'],r['column']] = True
```

Is there a faster way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will do `crosstab` with `update`

```
x.update(pd.crosstab(df.row,df.column).eq(1))
x
Out[44]: 
  Brazil Canada    USA
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3   True  False   True
4  False  False  False
5  False  False  False
6  False  False   True
7  False   True  False
```

Comment: Using `crosstab` is clever.

Comment: When I use that, it works, but some values on X are 'object' and not 'boolean' anymore. Any tips about that?

Comment: @LuizFernandoPuttowSouthier object ? can you print df.USA to check the type  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot the `positions` table:

```
s = (df.assign(dummy=True).set_index(['row','column'])
       ['dummy'].unstack(fill_value=False)
    )
x |= s
```

Output:

```
   Brazil  Canada    USA
1   False   False  False
2   False   False  False
3    True   False   True
4   False   False  False
5   False   False  False
6   False   False   True
7   False    True  False
```

Comment: I like the or_equals

Answer (score 2):

#### `searchsorted` and slice assignment with `iloc`

This assumes that `index` and `columns` in `x` are sorted.

We'll use `iloc` and tuples of positions to assign the value of `True`

---

```
i = tuple(x.index.searchsorted(df.row))
j = tuple(x.columns.searchsorted(df.column))

x.iloc[[i, j]] = True
x


   Brazil  Canada    USA
1   False   False  False
2   False   False  False
3    True   False   True
4   False   False  False
5   False   False  False
6   False   False   True
7   False    True  False
```